# RxJava: Ignore some errors in a Flowable

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I have a `Flowable<T>` and errors that are subtype of `IgnoreThisError` I want to ignore (resulting in graceful completion), all other errors should be propagated downstream.

Kotlin example:

```
val f : Flowable<T> = ...
val g = f.onErrorComplete { it is IgnoreThisError }
```

This function onErrorComplete is what I need and does not exist...

Comment: Something like this:
```kotlin
f.onErrorComplete {
    when (it) {
        is IgnoreThisError -> ...  
        else -> throw it      
    }
}
```

Comment: @NickRyan The whole reason for the question is that there's no `onErrorComplete` for `Flowable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
f.onErrorResumeNext {
    if (it is IgnoreThisError)
        Flowable.empty()
    else
        Flowable.error(it)
}
```

I am not sure if Kotlin can infer types properly here due to overloading and Java's emulation of variance in signatures, if not you may need to be more explicit:

```
f.onErrorResumeNext(Function<Throwable, Publisher<T>> {
    if (it is IgnoreThisError)
        Flowable.empty()
    else
        Flowable.error(it)
})
```

Comment: Jepp, that’s the same solution I found. The compiler indeed went crazy without proper annotation...

Comment: Of course, if you need it more than once, you can just define `onErrorComplete` extension function.

Comment: In generalized the solution in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for the missing `onErrorComplete` as an extension function:

```
/**
 * Errors encountered in the stream for which the provided `predicate` returns true will be silently turned into graceful completion.
 */
@CheckReturnValue
@BackpressureSupport(BackpressureKind.FULL)
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
inline fun <T> Flowable<T>.onErrorComplete(crossinline predicate: (Throwable) -> Boolean): Flowable<T> =
  onErrorResumeNext { error: Throwable ->
    if (predicate(error)) Flowable.empty<T>() else Flowable.error<T>(error)
  }
```

Note that I had to put an explicit `error: Throwable ->`, otherwise the compiler would complain because of the overloads of `onErrorResumeNext`.

Comment: Instead of suppressing you can use a name other than `it` e.g. `error: Throwable -> ...`. `@NonNull` is also strictly speaking redundant since Kotlin will add `@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` annotation.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the answer.

Comment: Btw this is the underlying problem I tried to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55529892/3612643